# OpenCV Sample Program lkdemo

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

reference, OpenCv\samples\c\lkdemo.c

Anybody know what does the following snippet of codes does ?

Code extracted from lkdemo.c

```
 for( i = k = 0; i < count; i++ )
            {
                if( add_remove_pt )
                {
                    double dx = pt.x - points[1][i].x;
                    double dy = pt.y - points[1][i].y;

                    if( dx*dx + dy*dy <= 25 )
                    {
                        add_remove_pt = 0;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if( !status[i] )
                    continue;

                points[1][k++] = points[1][i];
                cvCircle( image, cvPointFrom32f(points[1][i]), 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8,0);
            }
            count = k;
```

Q1.

What does the bold line does ?  >>  **points[1][k++] = points[1][i];**

Why k++ ? I am confuse, thinking that next point is overwritten by
the current point

Q2.

As cvCircle id drawn as the frame loops, where is the old points cleared and new point drawn ?

I look forward to your inputs.

Thanks =)

Answer (score 3):

Q1:

Perhaps it would help if I refactor the code:

```
if( status[i] ) {
    points[1][k++] = points[1][i];  // <---- Q1
    cvCircle( image, cvPointFrom32f(points[1][i]), 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8,0);
}
```

So in the line for question 1, i always increments (it's incremented by the loop) but k only increments when status[i] is true. In short, it eliminates any points in the array where status[i] is false by copying over them, and then setting the length of the array (count) to k, the number that passed the elimination.

Answer (score 1):

It's eliminating any points that have drifted more than 5 pixels (5*5=25).  k is being used to track the output index when points are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to figure out the where the clearing of points are done.
As frame loops the new points are reflected on the new frame and the new
frame refreshes the previous.

Answer (score 0):

Way out-dated, but for protocol's sake -

There's an open source Lucas Kanade app for the iPhone now - http://www.success-ware.com/150842/Lucas-Kanade-Detection-for-the-iPhone

It uses lkdemo code as well, and adds some extras around it.

You will find links to both an app on the AppStore and the project's source code in the link above.

HTH anyone,
Cheers,

Oded

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I get it. This block code eliminates any points where status[i] is false, that is, the ones that were in the previous image and were not found in the current image. But doing this, we're losing these points in our tracking, aren't we? I mean, if we are tracking an object with N px, every iterate we're dropping points out. Is that a good approach? Why to do this?